# Entity FrameWork with Oracle Database query takes very lonf time to execute

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

here's a C# Code in a WPF application that uses Entity FrameWorK connected to an Oracle Database to implement textboxes and Labels.

```
    private void BareCode_TxtBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
         using (Entities1 dc = new Entities1()) // Entity FrameWork connected to Oracle DataBase
                {
                 var query = from ach in dc.GCACHAT_DET
                                join art in dc.GCARTICLE on ach.ACH_ART_CODE equals art.ART_CODE
                                join emb in dc.GCEMBALLAGE on art.ART_CODE_EMB equals emb.EMB_CODE
                                where ach.ACH_LOT == LotAka // LotAka is a Double
                                select new
                                {
                                    ach.ACH_DATE_CREAT,
                                    ach.ACH_DLC,
                                    ach.ACH_TRACABILITE,
                                    ach.ACH_PDS_NET_REC,
                                    ach.ACH_COLIS_REC,
                                    ach.ACH_LOT,
                                    art.ART_CODE,
                                    art.ART_LIB1,
                                    art.ART_RUB2,
                                    art.ART_PDS_NET,
                                    art.ART_DLC,
                                    emb.EMB_TARE_VENTE
                                };
                    #endregion

                    // This part  takes lot of time to execute              
                    Produits_TxtBox.Text = query.First().ART_LIB1;
                    ArtCode_TB.Text = query.First().ART_CODE;
                    ArtCode = ArtCode_TB.Text;
                    SigleQ1TB.Text = query.First().ART_RUB2;
                    DLUO_TB.Text = query.First().ART_DLC.ToString();
                    HiddenTareCartonLB.Content = query.First().EMB_TARE_VENTE.ToString();
                    TCart_Text.Content = $"Tare Cartons (x {query.First().EMB_TARE_VENTE})";
                    Pnet_Text_LB.Content = $"Poids Net (x {query.First().ART_PDS_NET})";
                    string _lotQuant = query.First().ACH_TRACABILITE;
                    Lotquant = _lotQuant.Substring(0, _lotQuant.IndexOf(".") + 0);
                    #endregion
                    //....
                } 
        }
    }
```

This code is working fine but the part between "//" takes long time to execute. I'm wondering why. Is it the way i implement my textboxes or label with "query.firt()..." ? 
Is there a another to do it ?

If someone has an idea, please tell me.
Thanks

Comment: if I remember correct, multiple uses of `query.First()` are translated in multiple db queries. use local variable: `var result = query.First(); Produits_TxtBox.Text = result.ART_LIB1;` etc

Comment: like the first commenter said, everytime you call .First() you are executing the query again. Put .First() on your query definition so that is executed only once.  It will also change the type of query from an IQueryable to the anonymous type you are creating with the projection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was stated in the comments, calling First() everytime means re-running the query which is an expensive operation.
You don't have to separate the query from the first variable if you are only using the query to get the first element.

```
var _first = (from ach in dc.GCACHAT_DET
                            join art in dc.GCARTICLE on ach.ACH_ART_CODE equals art.ART_CODE
                            join emb in dc.GCEMBALLAGE on art.ART_CODE_EMB equals emb.EMB_CODE
                            where ach.ACH_LOT == LotAka // LotAka is a Double
                            select new
                            {
                                ach.ACH_DATE_CREAT,
                                ach.ACH_DLC,
                                ach.ACH_TRACABILITE,
                                ach.ACH_PDS_NET_REC,
                                ach.ACH_COLIS_REC,
                                ach.ACH_LOT,
                                art.ART_CODE,
                                art.ART_LIB1,
                                art.ART_RUB2,
                                art.ART_PDS_NET,
                                art.ART_DLC,
                                emb.EMB_TARE_VENTE
                            }).FirstOrDefault();
```